# Is there a way to apply transform (Ctrl+a) for every frame

Tags: modifiers

If I want to rotate a cube with the re-mesh block modifier, but have the blocks face one way as shown below, I would have to apply rotation every frame. Is there a way to do that?

[image]

[image]

As seen the cube rotates, but the block modifier itself does not. The blocks stay perfectly straight.

Comment: Why do you not apply the modifier? This would make the effect permanent and everything would move with the object coordinate system

Comment: I want for it every frame to change, at 0 degrees its flat, at 45 degrees its diagonal blocks